# add multi class to div

Tags: jquery

i wrote this script to ckech div hover. after hovering on div i want to change class of div to multi class

```
$('#chkm').hover(function(){ 
    $('#chkm').addClass(".main-quiz-holder .slide-container #hdiv");
});
```

my div:

```
<div style='float: right;' id='mdiv' >
  <ul class="styledlist" >
     <img src='images/system_help.png' id='ckekeKala' width='18px'/>
  </ul>
</div>
```

my css:

```
.main-quiz-holder .slide-container #mdiv {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    font-size:11px;
    color: rgb(76, 76, 76);
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset, 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(246, 246, 246), rgb(212, 212, 212)) repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(246, 246, 246);
    border: 1px solid rgb(161, 161, 161);
}
.main-quiz-holder .slide-container #hdiv {
    background: #ebe9f9; 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ebe9f9 0%, #d8d0ef 50%, #cec7ec 51%, #c1bfea 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ebe9f9), color-stop(50%,#d8d0ef), color-stop(51%,#cec7ec), color-stop(100%,#c1bfea));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ebe9f9 0%,#d8d0ef 50%,#cec7ec 51%,#c1bfea 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ebe9f9 0%,#d8d0ef 50%,#cec7ec 51%,#c1bfea 100%); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ebe9f9 0%,#d8d0ef 50%,#cec7ec 51%,#c1bfea 100%); 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ebe9f9 0%,#d8d0ef 50%,#cec7ec 51%,#c1bfea 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ebe9f9', endColorstr='#c1bfea',GradientType=0 ); 
}
```

Comment: `.` and `#` are not allowed in class names, thus you can't add `'.main-quiz-holder .slide-container #hdiv'` as CSS classes…

Answer (score 2):

Drop the dots from the class names, as [`.addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) expects class names as strings (and not selectors).

```
$('#chkm').addClass("main-quiz-holder slide-container");
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `.` in `addClass()` function

```
$('#chkm').hover(function(){ 
    $('#chkm').addClass("main-quiz-holder");
});
```

These two classes or a div have same css than you don't need to add them all.Using a single will also works fine

Answer (score 1):

This should be good

```
$('#chkm').addClass("main-quiz-holder slide-container #hdiv");
```

The . dot is not required when adding or removing the class names.
It is only required when trying to use it as a selector..